# How to get the address/offset of the struct member for serialization purposes

Tags: c++, struct, pointer-to-member

I am trying to implement a function that sets a struct member and also serializes the data to an external output. For serialization purposes, I need to know the size and offset of the struct member, but I am struggling to obtain the offset.

In the following code, when I print the value of `member`, I get correct values, but I'm not able to convert it to integer.

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:36,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Astruct+Data+%7B%0A++++int32_t+i%3B%0A++++uint32_t+u%3B%0A++++bool+b%3B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AData+g_data%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Type%3E%0Avoid+set(Type+Data::*member,+const+Type%26+value)%0A%7B%0A++++//+Works+for+printing%0A++++printf(%22Size:+%25lu%5CtAddress+%3D+%25lu%5Cn%22,+sizeof(Type),+member)%3B%0A%0A++++//+Invalid+cast+error%0A++++//+printf(%22Size:+%25lu%5CtAddress+%3D+%25lu%5Cn%22,+sizeof(Type),+reinterpret_cast%3Cuintptr_t%3E(member))%3B%0A%0A++++//+Works,+but+unnecesarily+complex%3F%0A++++//+printf(%22Size:+%25lu%5CtAddress+%3D+%25lu%5Cn%22,+sizeof(Type),+reinterpret_cast%3Cuintptr_t%3E(%26(g_data.*member))+-+reinterpret_cast%3Cuintptr_t%3E(%26g_data))%3B%0A%0A++++g_data.*member+%3D+value%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++set(%26Data::i,+static_cast%3Cint32_t%3E(1))%3B%0A++++set(%26Data::u,+static_cast%3Cuint32_t%3E(2U))%3B%0A++++set(%26Data::b,+true)%3B%0A++++set(%26Data::c,+!%271!%27)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O2%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:71.32796780684104,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27AVR+gcc+12.1.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:28.67203219315896,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```c++
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Data {
    int32_t i;
    uint32_t u;
    bool b;
    char c;
};

Data g_data;

template <typename Type>
void set(Type Data::*member, const Type& value)
{
    // Works for printing
    printf("Size: %lu\tAddress = %lu\n", sizeof(Type), member);

    // Invalid cast error
    // printf("Size: %lu\tAddress = %lu\n", sizeof(Type), reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(member));

    // Works, but unnecesarily complex?
    // printf("Size: %lu\tAddress = %lu\n", sizeof(Type), reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&(g_data.*member)) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&g_data));

    g_data.*member = value;
}

int main() {
    set(&Data::i, static_cast<int32_t>(1));
    set(&Data::u, static_cast<uint32_t>(2U));
    set(&Data::b, true);
    set(&Data::c, '1');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof

Comment: You should introduce two parameter types for `set` to allow implicit conversion.

Comment: @Evg I know about `offsetof`, but I could not apply it to my templated parameter. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why would you need to know such things? You can serialize without this information, you just refer to the struct members when reading and writing, and, hopefully, accounting for endian concerns with each datatype. Most serializers are a series of `write(...)` operations where that's often a template function that can account for the type of data being written, or more explicitly like `write_uint32_t` etc.

Comment: @Lingxi whether implicit conversions are desirable, is a matter of taste, I suppose.

Comment: @tadman Each strut member needs to be written to a fixed memory location.

Comment: @Armandas I don't think so. What happens if `int` and `unsigned` are not 32-bit? Your template may fail to deduce the single `Type`.

Comment: @Lingxi that is the case on my system, but I'm not sure why it matters. I would like to avoid cases, where someone writes `3` to `bool` or `float` to `uint32_t` etc.

Comment: @Lingxi I guess the issue is my example code. I fixed it.

Comment: I guess there is no way to find an offset without using `offsetof`. All tricks with `reinterpret_cast` are not guaranteed to work.

Comment: I get that, but the way this is usually done is by writing a serializer function that works with the properties as code, not as some abstract pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the offset of a data member in a class type, you have two options:

#### [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)

```cpp
// in <cstddef>
#define offsetof(type, member) /* implementation-defined */
```

This macro expands to an integral constant expression of type `std::size_t` and gives us the offset in bytes from the start of the type.
This is exactly what you want.

However, to use it, `set` would need to take the offset instead of the pointer to the data member:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void set(std::size_t offset, const T& value)
{
    std::printf("Size: %zu\tAddress = %zu\n", sizeof(T), offset);
    // may require std::addressof to be safe against overloads of &
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&g_data), &value, sizeof(value));
}

int main()
{
    set(offsetof(Data, i), std::int32_t{1});
    set(offsetof(Data, u), std::uint32_t{2});
    set(offsetof(Data, b), true);
    set(offsetof(Data, c), '1');
}
```

*Note 1: the proper format specifier for `std::size_t` is `%zu`, not `%lu`.*

*Note 2: `offsetof` requires `Data` to be a standard layout type, and writing to its bytes like this requires it to be a trivially copyable type. For a simple struct like yours, this is the case.*

#### [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)

`std::bit_cast` is a C++20 function which takes the bytes of one object, and converts it to another object with the same bytes, but different type. Since pointers to data members are typically just an offset under the hood, this would work:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void set(Type Data::*member, const T& value)
{
    std::printf("Size: %zu\tAddress = %zu\n",
                sizeof(T),
                std::bit_cast<std::size_t>(member));
    g_data.*member = value;
}

int main()
{
    set(&Data::i, std::int32_t{1});
    set(&Data::u, std::uint32_t{2});
    set(&Data::b, true);
    set(&Data::c, '1');
}
```

However, while this technically works and is closer to your original code, **do not do this**. It makes too many assumptions about the implementation, namely:

1. how pointers to data members are represented under the hood
2. that pointers to data members have the same size as `std::size_t`

With some clever metaprogramming you could solve **2.** by choosing an integer with matching size, but **1.** is not solvable.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking something alone these lines, possibly with a macro wrapper to make the interface simpler, but wanted to avoid macros if possible. Any idea how conversion is possible with `printf`?

Comment: @Armandas not sure what you mean? Conversion of what exactly? `printf` is only printing a size and address here, so `%zu` is always right and doesn't need to be converted. If you don't know the printed type due to working with a template, then `std::cout` is much better.

Comment: I mean `printf` is able to print out the offset, so conversion to an integer is happening. I can't find a way to make the same conversion for storing in a variable.

Comment: In the first solution `printf` is just printing out the `offset` which already is a `std::size_t`, so no conversion is necessary. If you want to read one of the data members, you create a variable of same right type and `std::memcpy` out of `g_data` into it. To write to data member, you use `std::memcpy` as shown in the code.